# Keycloak - Customize reset credentials flow

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

I need to customize the reset credentials flow, by intercepting the password and OTP authentication. I made a few tests extending `org.keycloak.authentication.authenticators.resetcred.ResetOTP` and `org.keycloak.authentication.authenticators.resetcred.ResetPassword`, but in neither case the debug stopped, and I can't find in the documentation the implementation for this actions.

Does anybody knows which classes are being used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found my own way: the class that updates the password in the Reset credentials flow is `org.keycloak.authentication.requiredactions.UpdatePassword` and the class that validates the TOTP is `org.keycloak.authentication.requiredactions.UpdateTotp`. So, I just created a custom class that extends each one, redefined the method `void processAction(RequiredActionContext context)` (executing by the end `super.processAction(context)` to let Keycloak do its magic), and finally registered both customizations in a new file, named `org.keycloak.authentication.RequiredActionFactory` and located in the META-INF/services folder.